# Create new html from an existing html link using Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a html web page that I am sourcing using a python script and need to create a new html doc using the existing one(html elements). Is there a way to do this. I researched and could find ways to append into an existing one but not how to create new html doc/page out of it. Below is the snippet and the one in blue is that I want to create a new html page out of.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `create a new html doc using the existing one(html elements)`? Your code trials?

Comment: I mean this complete html doc has two td tags (22% of element resides in one tag and rest 78% in other td tag). I just need to use the tag with 78% of the elements and use that to create a new html page. Does that make sense.Pardon my limited understanding of Python.

Comment: `to create a new html page` why do you need **selenium**?

Comment: My bad I had used Selenium to get on to this webpage which is the preceding part of the code that I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that I have used to create the new html doc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request,os,datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://mylink")
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[href*=PublicInfoServlet]") #finding the weblinks(html doc) I need to edit and create new html docs
for elem in elems: #iterate through all the html weblinks found on the main webpage
    abc=elem.get_attribute("href")
    print(abc)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(abc)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    a=soup.find("div", {"id": "SpanPrint"}) #identify the html tag that needs to be used to create the required html document
    efg = (abc.split("=", 1)[1])
    hig=(efg.split('&', 1)[0])
    f = open(str(hig)+'.html', 'w')
    message=str(a)
    f.write(message)
    f.close()

    # Change path to reflect file location
    x = str(datetime.date.today())
    b = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    c = x[0:10]
    d = b[11:19]
    e = str(c + d).replace(':', '')
    filename = 'mypath' +str(hig)+'.html' #saving the new doc at the required location.
    os.rename('mypath'.html',
              'mypath' +str(hig) + e + '.html')
driver.quit()
```